# Is it possible to build seed dataset/table over multiple files in DBT?

Tags: dbt, dbtype, dbt-cloud

Is it possible to build seed dataset/table over multiple files in DBT?

I have two data files like below in my dbt project

[image]

Building seed dataset/table on individual file works perfectly fine.

However, what I am looking for is to create one seed dataset/table locations which should have the combined data from both the files.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this directly using `dbt seed`. The easiest approach is to keep them separate seed files resulting in 2 source tables, then just create a model that combines them. The model is as simple as

```
{{ dbt_utils.union_relations(relations=[
    source('locations', 'locations_1'), 
    source('locations', 'locations_2')
]) }}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam!
The thing is, in my actual scenario I have around 200 static files which all have the same structure, and I don't want to end up creating 200 different tables and keep editing the code whenever a new file is added.

Comment: You can code it to loop through the sources, but your first point about not wanting 200 tables makes sense. I'm also assuming that these files aren't completely static and/or the number of files changes frequently enough so that you can't simply merge them into a single file beforehand and use that as the seed? If not, then I would recommend doing the ingestion outside of DBT. Pretty much any destination can trigger a write once a file is written to cloud storage (ie, write to S3 -> trigger Snowpipe to write to Snowflake if using AWS/Snowflake).

Comment: The files themselves are pretty small, two columns with 10-20 rows and rarely need to be changed.

Cannot set it up as ingestion as its a manual file sent out by business once or twice a month.

The best solution then for us would be to keep these files the ADLS storage and build a external  table on top of that location in Databricks which we are already doing for properly ingested data from different source systems.